# Sqlalchemy column_property math

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm working with Invoice and Payment models, trying to determine how much money is due to be paid for an Invoice based on Payments for an Invoice.

I have come up with the following, making use of Sqlalchemy's column_proprty:

```
# Total amount for an Invoice
Invoice.total_rands = column_property(
    select([func.sum(InvoiceProduct.sub_total_rands)]).where(InvoiceProduct.invoice_id==Invoice.id).correlate(Invoice)
)

# Total amount which needs to be paid.
Invoice.amount_due_rands = column_property(
    Invoice.total_rands - select([func.sum(Payment.amount_rands)]).where(Payment.invoice_id==Invoice.id).correlate(Invoice)
)
```

This issue with the above code is that if there are no Payments for an Invoice, the Invoice's 'amount_due_rands' is None and not equal to Invoice.total_rands.

So I guess I have two questions:

1. How (using my current solution) could I have the Invoice.amount_due_rands column_proprty return Invoice.total_rands if there are no Payments for an Invoice.
2. How else could I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoice.amount_due_rands = column_property(
    Invoice.total_rands - select([func.coalesce(func.sum(Payment.amount_rands), 0)]).where(Payment.invoice_id==Invoice.id).correlate(Invoice)
)

Comment: Thank you, func.coalesce is what I was looking for.